# CALCULO PROMEDIO DE DIAS CON DOS CAMPOS FECHA

Tags: sql-server

Cordial saludo,

como se puede realizar el calculo del promedio entre fechas en sql server e intentado con lo siguiente:

```
SELECT SUM((DATEDIFF(DAY,HPNESTANC.HESFECING,HPNESTANC.HESFECSAL)))  
FROM HPNESTANC 
WHERE HPNESTANC.HPNDEFCAM IN (80,237, 238,239,240,241,242,243,244,
245,247,248,249,245,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,256,357) 
AND HPNESTANC.HESFECING BETWEEN '01-01-2018' AND  '31-01-2018'
```

eso me arroja 147 dias de estancia, pero entonces como seria el promedio?

esta consulta me arroja 80 registros, debo dividirlo entre los 80 registros? de las fechas?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En vez del  `sum` puedes usar directamente `avg`, verifica esto: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177677(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Si lo intente pero solo me saca el promedio de la fecha de ingreso, tambien necesito la de la fecha de egreso.

Comment: Esto: `AVG((DATEDIFF(DAY,HPNESTANC.HESFECING,HPNESTANC.HESFECSAL)))` te debería dar el promedio de la diferencia de días. ¿Es eso lo que buscas?